# Update Foreign Key within row ASP.NET MVC, Entity.Modified

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, foreign-keys

Currently I am working on changing the values within a table row, which includes the following variables:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Item_Name { get; set; }
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.##}")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
public int TimeSlot { get; set; }
public bool Food_AddOns { get; set; }
public bool Drink_AddOns { get; set; }
public virtual Item_Description Item_Description { get; set; }
public virtual Item_Status Item_Status { get; set; }
public virtual Dinner Dinner { get; set; }
public string Ingredients { get; set; }
```

My View passes the values that are given from the user to this model:

```
public class Edit_AddItemModel
{
[Display(Name = "ID")]
public int ID { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Item Name:")]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 1)]
public string New_ItemName { get; set; }
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.##}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Display(Name = "Price:")]
public decimal New_Price { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Time Slot:")]
public int New_TimeSlot { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Lunch Special?:")]
public bool New_Food_AddOns { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Free Drink?:")]
public bool Drink_AddOns { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Item Description:")]
public string New_Item_Description { get; set; }
public bool New_spicy { get; set; }
public bool New_gluten { get; set; }
public bool New_vegetarian { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Dinner:")]
public string New_Dinner { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Ingredients:")]
[StringLength(140, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 0)]
public string New_Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

My values are passed correctly to the controller as illustrated in the image below, and is passed to a function called Edit_CheckAllValues. This is what the Edit_CheckAllValues looks like, which basically creates an ItemsModel Object with the what has been passed from the View:

```
private ItemsModel Edit_CheckAllValues(ItemsModel NewItem, Edit_AddItemModel model)
    {
        int CurrentItem_ItemStatus;
        NewItem.ID = model.ID;
        NewItem.Item_Name = model.New_ItemName;
        NewItem.Price = model.New_Price;
        NewItem.TimeSlot = model.New_TimeSlot;
        NewItem.Food_AddOns = model.New_Food_AddOns;
        NewItem.Drink_AddOns = model.Drink_AddOns;
        NewItem.Item_Description = convertToForeignKey_ItemDescription(Convert.ToInt32(model.New_Item_Description));
        //Get Current Item Status. 
        CurrentItem_ItemStatus = get_ItemStatus(model.New_spicy, model.New_gluten, model.New_vegetarian);
        NewItem.Item_Status = convertToForeignKey_ItemStatus(CurrentItem_ItemStatus);
        NewItem.Dinner = convertToForeignKey_Dinner(Convert.ToInt32(model.New_Dinner));
        NewItem.Ingredients = model.New_Ingredients;
        return NewItem;
    }
```

An Example of what is returned, what the new ItemModel looks like, which contains the ID of the item I want to edit: The Return Value:
[image]

An Example of one of the foreign keys being changed from ID: 20 to ID: 2 Item Description Foreign Key Change:
[image]

The New Object is then passed back to the original ActionResult EditItem, which it is changing the state of the item selected, which works correctly when changing variables that are not foreign keys such as price, Item Name, TimeSlot, etc:

```
public ActionResult EditItem(EditItemModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ItemsModel newItem = new ItemsModel();
            newItem = Edit_CheckAllValues(newItem, model.edit_AddItemModel);
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            db.Items.Attach(newItem);   //Tired both with Attach and Without Attach
            db.Entry(newItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("ChangeItems", "Employee");
    }
```

I'm not sure where in my code I need to make edits, but my guess is I need to grab the row first within my Edit_CheckAllValues instead of passing the values into a new Object and sending it to the database using EntityState.Modified.

Any help would be appreciated, for I have been stuck on this question for 3 days now.

Answer (score 0):

Based off the reference to this page ([ASP.Net MVC 4 Update value linked to a foreign key column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195947/asp-net-mvc-4-update-value-linked-to-a-foreign-key-column))

I was able to figure out the problem. The portions I needed to update were my ItemsModel:

```
public class ItemsModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Item_Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.##}")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int TimeSlot { get; set; }
    public bool Food_AddOns { get; set; }
    public bool Drink_AddOns { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Item_Description")]
    public virtual int Item_Description_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Item_Description Item_Description { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Item_Status")]
    public virtual int Item_Status_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Item_Status Item_Status { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Dinner")]
    public virtual int Dinner_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Dinner Dinner { get; set; }
    public string Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

Adding the [ForeignKey] from the API: using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

and update my Edit_CheckAllValues function:

```
private ItemsModel Edit_CheckAllValues(ItemsModel NewItem, Edit_AddItemModel model)
    {
        int CurrentItem_ItemStatus;
        NewItem.ID = model.ID;
        NewItem.Item_Name = model.New_ItemName;
        NewItem.Price = model.New_Price;
        NewItem.TimeSlot = model.New_TimeSlot;
        NewItem.Food_AddOns = model.New_Food_AddOns;
        NewItem.Drink_AddOns = model.Drink_AddOns;
        //NewItem.Item_Description = convertToForeignKey_ItemDescription(Convert.ToInt32(model.New_Item_Description));
        NewItem.Item_Description_ID = Convert.ToInt32(model.New_Item_Description);
        //Get Current Item Status. 

        CurrentItem_ItemStatus = get_ItemStatus(model.New_spicy, model.New_gluten, model.New_vegetarian);
        NewItem.Item_Status_ID = CurrentItem_ItemStatus;
        //  NewItem.Item_Status = convertToForeignKey_ItemStatus(CurrentItem_ItemStatus);
        NewItem.Dinner_ID = 163;    //Ignore this is my empty default Dinner. 
       // NewItem.Dinner = convertToForeignKey_Dinner(Convert.ToInt32(model.New_Dinner));
      //  CurrentItem.Item_Description = convertToForeignKey_ItemDescription(Convert.ToInt32(model.New_Item_Description));
        NewItem.Ingredients = model.New_Ingredients;
        return NewItem;
    }
```

The entity-modified will finally register the changes to the foreign keys.